# Retrieve data from S3 using s3_files on Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am pretty new to Chef and trying to retrieve data from my s3 bucket with s3_files chef cookbook on chef supermarket .

I did the following steps :

Install chef sdk

Generate cookbook with Berkshelf:

`chef generate cookbook pizza -b`

Filling depends in metadata.rb:

```
name 'pizza'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures pizza'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 16.0'
depends  's3_file', '~> 2.8.5'
```

My Bersfile:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
```

runlist.json:

```
{ 
   "run_list": [ "recipe[pizza]"] 
}
```

solo.rb

```
current_dir       = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
file_cache_path   "#{current_dir}"
cookbook_path     "#{current_dir}/cookbooks"
role_path         "#{current_dir}/roles"
data_bag_path     "#{current_dir}/data_bags"
```

recipe (default.rb file)

```
s3_file "/home/test" do
    remote_path "app.py"
    bucket "bucket-ex5"
    aws_access_key_id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    aws_secret_access_key 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    action :create
end
```

I am running with the following command
`chef-solo -c solo.rb -j runlist.json`

I receive the following error :

```
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: s3_file
```

I would appreciate your assist and help !